# Is .5 same as 0.5 in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, numbers

In a C++ file, I read a statement as follows:

```
return cos((x-centre)*2*M_PI*recipwidth)*.5+.5;
```

Is the `.5` in the above statement same as `0.5`?

Comment: Yes, `0.5` and `.5` represent the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the standard has to say about it in §2.14.4 [lex.fcon]/1 (emphasis mine):

> A floating literal consists of an integer part, a decimal point, a fraction part, an e or E, an optionally signed integer exponent, and an optional type suffix. The integer and fraction parts both consist of a sequence of decimal (base ten) digits. **Either the integer part or the fraction part (not both) can be omitted**; either the decimal point or the letter e (or E ) and the exponent (not both) can be omitted.

So yes, `0.5` and `.5` are equivalent.